# IMovie HD Recovery

Tags: data-recovery, imovie, mac-os-classic

15 years ago Apple had iMovie HD and it was great. I have a few projects that I made in iMovie HD and I would like to recover them.

I think I need to install a Mac OS virtual machine somehow, install iMovie HD on that and then open the files there. Any ideas how to install a Mac OS virtual machine? (Ie where the images are?)

**Possible Solutions I Found/Heard:**

- SheepShaver to install a Mac OS 9 virtualization, install iMovie HD then open the files
- install iLife 06 on a Mac or Mac virtualization (it looks like I need Mountain Lion) and open the files there.

Comment: Relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/64961/24324
Also, what have you tried so far in terms of opening th iMovie HD project? Have you looked for alternative ways? Please include your research in the question, to prevent that others suggest solutions you've tried already.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke my research has turned up sheepshaver, and the link you sent also recommends that solution. Is it better to install sheepshaver on Mac OS X or Linux?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to start with "What's the newest version of iMove that will still open my file?", because it's a whole lot easier to run Mountain Lion in a VM than OS 9. You can also still get hold of iLife 06, which was still "iMovie HD" at that point.

Comment: Great to see that you've looked into solutions already. Could you please [edit] your question to include things you've looked into so far? Also I agree with Tetsujins suggestion.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can run iLife 06? Where would I get that? it looks like the download link has been removed.

Comment: @brothman01 The usual thing to try would be a google for "ilife 06 download", maybe an ISO image has been saved on some archive site. Or eBay for the DVD.

Comment: @AndrewMorton but even if I buy the DVD from eBay I will not be able to open iLife 06 on a modern Mac. What do I do about that?

Comment: Figure what it will run on & set that up as a VM. Much easier than SheepShaver. Try VMWare Fusion - free for home use.

Comment: I have some old computers in storage that I am going to check for use for this. I may have to buy the power chords for the computers. How can I verify which chords to buy?